# Not able to browse SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, windows-7, windows-authentication

I am trying to browse SharePoint site(host header site collection site ) on my windows 7 machine where it is deployed but When i try to browse this site it prompts to enter credential.I am entering the correct credentials still it is prompting again and again.
i am able to browse other SharePoint sites successfully.

I have tried DisableLoopbackCheck also.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this on Win7, but on Win2k8 Server, this is a common issue. You have to disable the loopback check. Check out http://davidlozzi.com/2011/10/07/cant-log-into-sharepoint-from-the-console/

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have correct permissions to view the site. Go to Central Admin and try adding yourself as a site collection admin to the site and try accessing again.

Comment: i have permission to the site and i am site collection admin as well

Comment: hope you are using Windows authentication mode and its enabled in IIS. Pls verify it in authentication modes in IIS